# How to add a builtin indicator in my pine script code?

Tags: pine-script

I want to build a script in pine script where I want to a buitin script on the chart with my other functionalities how can i do it ? i want to plot linear regression trend lines not the regression line. you can check here below. i want like this

[image: Linear Regession]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include built-ins written in JavaScript in Pine scripts. You could always connect to one of their inputs, but in your case the best solution will be to find open-source code in the Public Library and make sure you respect the reuse [House Rules](https://www.tradingview.com/house-rules/#scripts) when you reuse it.